# parse uri in android using substring or trim

Tags: android, uri

I have this url and I want to parse the only content after = symbol

I have this code which works fine but substring and other thing, I tried is not working.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);


    <a rel="nofollow" href="whatsapp://send?text=चोट इस कदर खाई है दिल ने की अब कोई लडकी Awwww भी करती है, तो लगता है ये थोड़ी देर में फद्&zwnj;दू बना देगी!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" ><span class="whatsapp">&nbsp;</span></a>
```

I want all contents of href after **whatsapp://send?text=** so if I chose after = using substring it should work but its not working as it is giving error

Comment: Can you tell me any url that has space in between words. why don't you put + sign in between words after = and then try.

Comment: @Tauqir i dont have control on text so i cant put but i know that all url will contains these words so i can trim after =whatsapp://send?text=

Comment: does your url changes always?

Comment: @Tauqir yes but  whatsapp://send?text= remains in all

Comment: replace " " spacing in url or else your url won't be a valid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String result = uri.getQuery().split("=")[1]

getQuery() will return "text=blabla".

split("=") splits up the string into an array of sub strings.

Select the second half (index 1)

Comment: its just working as i want. but whatsapp shares <br> and other html parameters also. i want only text. if i remove html then formatting will not be good